# Angular2 [Typescript] Services Clash across components

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to a include service into 3 components here.
here is my structure:

app-page

| - comp1

| - comp2

both the components are displayed on the same page -> app page, one of them is in router-outlet and other one is just outside.

```
public constructor(spinner: SpinnerService) {}
```

but when I add above code in both components I get below error:

```
Error: BaseException@http://localhost:9000/node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js:5116:27
CompileMetadataResolver</CompileMetadataResolver.prototype.getDependenciesMetadata@http://localhost:9000/node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js:13527:23
CompileMetadataResolver</CompileMetadataResolver.prototype.getTypeMetadata@http://localhost:9000/node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js:13424:25
CompileMetadataResolver</CompileMetadataResolver.prototype.getDirectiveMetadata@http://localhost:9000/node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js:13176:27
CompileMetadataResolver</CompileMetadataResolver.prototype.getNgModuleMetadata/<@http://localhost:9000/node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js:13267:47
CompileMetadataResolver</CompileMetadataResolver.prototype.getNgModuleMetadata@http://localhost:9000/node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js:13261:21
RuntimeCompiler</RuntimeCompiler.prototype._compileComponents@http://localhost:9000/node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js:15845:28
RuntimeCompiler</RuntimeCompiler.prototype._compileModuleAndComponents@http://localhost:9000/node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js:15769:36
RuntimeCompiler</RuntimeCompiler.prototype.compileModuleAsync@http://localhost:9000/node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js:15746:20
PlatformRef_</PlatformRef_.prototype._bootstrapModuleWithZone@http://localhost:9000/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:9991:20
PlatformRef_</PlatformRef_.prototype.bootstrapModule@http://localhost:9000/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:9984:20
.execute@http://localhost:9000/build/boot.js:14:13
Zone</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke@http://localhost:9000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:323:20
Zone</Zone</Zone.prototype.run@http://localhost:9000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:216:25
scheduleResolveOrReject/<@http://localhost:9000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:571:53
Zone</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:9000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:356:24
Zone</Zone</Zone.prototype.runTask@http://localhost:9000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:256:29
drainMicroTaskQueue@http://localhost:9000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:474:26
ZoneTask/this.invoke@http://localhost:9000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:426:22

Error loading http://localhost:9000/build/boot.jslocalhost:9000:18:51
```

source code for one of the component:

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
 import {  LoaderModel } from '../../x/loader/core';
 import { SpinnerService } from '../../x/loader/service';


 declare var __moduleName: string;


 @Component({

  templateUrl: 'template.html',

  moduleId: __moduleName


 })

 export class AuthenticationComponent {



 public constructor(private _spinner: SpinnerService) {}



 Login() {

     this._spinner.start("LOL")

 alert("all Okies");

 }


 }
```

Module:

```
import { NgModule }                     from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule }                from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { routing, appRoutingProviders } from './routing';

import { axComponent }  from './core';
import { AuthenticationComponent }  from '../../x/authentication/core';
import { ForgotPasswordComponent }  from '../../x/credentials/forgot/password/core';
import { LoaderComponent }  from '../../x/loader/core';
import { SpinnerService } from '../../x/loader/service';


@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, routing ],
  declarations: [ alphaComponent, AuthenticationComponent, ForgotPasswordComponent, LoaderComponent ],
  providers:    [ appRoutingProviders, SpinnerService ],
  bootstrap:    [ axComponent ]
})
export class alphaModule {

}
```

When I remove it from one of the Component it would start working again.

But I need it on both the components, is there any solution for this?

---

Edit: I checked it without rotuer-oulet and both components were working but the moment you add one of them into the router-outlet it would start throwing error.

Is is a bug on Angular2 side?

Comment: can you please share component code?

Comment: added the code for a component.

Comment: Are all the components under the same module with this service declared as a provider?

Comment: yes they are all are under same module, added the module code in the description.

Comment: Try removing `moduleId: __moduleName` from all 3 components and see what happens.

Comment: Same Result, no luck.

Comment: Just wanted you all to know that one of the components is in router-outlet and other one is just outside.

Comment: @Jimq could you create a plunkr?